# finding the complex eigenvalues from complex eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra

The question:

A system of differential equations can be created for two masses connected by springs between one another, and connected to opposing walls. The dependent variables form a 4 × 1 vector y consisting of the displacement and velocity of each of the two masses. For the system y′  =  Ay, the matrix A is given by:

\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\-37&3&-4&0\\3&-37&0&-4\end{bmatrix}

Because the system oscillates, there will be complex eigenvalues. Find the eigenvalue associated with the following eigenvector.

\begin{bmatrix}-4i\\4i\\24+8i\\-24-8i\end{bmatrix}

I thought about this question, and it would be easy if the matrix was in 2x2 form and i could use the quadratic formula to find the complex eigenvalues. But with a 4x4 matrix I am not sure how to proceed. So just to give it a try I found the determinant by reducing the matrix into upper triangular form:

\begin{bmatrix}-37&3&-4&0\\3&-37&0&-4\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

Thus eigenvalues = $\lambda-37$ and $\lambda= 1$

If I have started correctly, how do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Each eigenvector should corresponds to only one eigenvalue.
- By definition, an eigenvector satisfies $Av = \lambda v$.
- From $Av=\lambda v$, the first row gives us the constraint that $$24+8i = \lambda (-4i).$$
- We just have to solve for $\lambda$.

Comment: So $\lambda = 8i$?

Comment: can't be. if the answer is $8i$, the RHS would be negative but the LHS is not a real number. $\lambda = \frac{24+8i}{-4i}=\frac{6+2i}{-i}=2 \cdot \frac{3+i}{-i}$. Can you simplify it by multiplying both the numerator and denominator by $i$?

Comment: you are right, thanks.

Comment: ahh sorry, it would be $2-6i$ but this returned as incorrect answer in my assignment.

Comment: I get $-2+6i$, can you check if you made a sign error mistake?

Comment: argh, seems the 10 hours of math i have been doing today has taken its toll. Yes you are right. it is $-2+6i$ thank you

Comment: Why are you specifically choosing $λ=\frac{24+8i}{−4i}$

Comment: The first row has lots of $0$ and a single $1$, so I just pick the first row of the equation $Av=\lambda v$ to obtain an equation. You can pick the other rows as well. Second row would be simple too.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is wrong.  To find eigenvalues you need to equate $\det(A-\lambda I)$ to zero then solve.  That is, you have to subtract $\lambda I$ then find the determinant - you seem to have (partially) found the determinant then subtracted $\lambda I$.

However, the problem is actually much easier than this.  To say that a non-zero vector $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ means
$$Av=\lambda v\ ;$$
since you have been given $A$ and $v$, it is easy to use this equation to find $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

We have to get 
 $$Av=\lambda v$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\-37&3&-4&0\\3&-37&0&-4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-4i\\4i\\24+8i\\-24-8i\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}24+8i\\-24-8i\\-96+128i\\96-128i\end{bmatrix} =(-2+6i)\begin{bmatrix}-4i\\4 i\\24+8i\\-24-8i\end{bmatrix}   $$

Thus the eigenvalue is $-2+6i$

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I do not see the logic (also your answer was wrong as per my assignment)

Comment: @TheoBendit  Oh, yes. Thanks for the comment. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Forextrader The logic is $Av=\lambda v$ sure you see the logic. The typo is fixed now.

Comment: Sorry, but how were you able to find $(-2+6i)?

Comment: @Forextrader  $ (24+8i)/(-4i) = -2+6i$